# How to install .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10 Creators?

Tags: .net, windows

I just got a new laptop with Windows 10 Creators, which comes with .NET Framework 4.7.  My application target .NET 4.6.2, but I can't install .NET 4.6.2 because it says that "a later update is already installed on this computer".  How can I get .NET 4.6.2 on my computer?

UPDATE:

I had to install the .NET 4.6.2 Developer Pack, that one worked.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: Does that break your app? If your asking because you want to add development support install the develop pack from  https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting

Comment: what about deployment of your app in windows 10 creator machine. Would not it break there

Comment: I'm creating websites that are just installed on a web server where I control the framework versions.

Answer (score 4):

I'd the same issue but later figured out that I should install the 4.6.2 developer pack
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53321

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: I would never remember that I cannot install actual runtime but i need to install dev pack instead. finally it worked!

Answer (score 0):

According to your update, you may be able to open the project in your development environment( installing developer pack) but you need to consider the fact about deploying the same to customer (who will have fresh windows creator update machine).

With Windows creator update machine, .net 4.5.7 is by default installed as part of OS and uninstalling it manually is not recommended.

> So, you got two options:
>
> Option 1.(IMHO it is better) upgrade your project target architecture
>   to latest 4.5.7 which requires thorough regression testing of your
>   app. As it might break something(not sure about this). But It is wise
>   to double check.
>
> Option 2. While upgrading the windows to creator update ask customer
>   to block update latest release of .net by using following
>
> https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/12/blocking-net-framework-4-7-installation/

bit weird solution. But don't have any other solution.

If anyone else is also facing this issue, then do let me know a better solution.

Answer (score -3):

Visit [Raymond's blog](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-install-all-versions-of-net-framework-plus-hotfixes-with-aio-runtimes/)  for a silent all-in-one installer that will first purge your laptop of all versions and reinstall each to the latest after that. That's your best bet!